# Global control handler

Tags: android

I have an Android service that runs in background.
I need it to recieve feedback (and stop, for example) just when user did something, no matter if it's only touch event on homescreen of somewhere else or key press.

Is it possible to handle global touch and key events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I highly doubt that there is an easy way to do this, you can register intents and intercept the messages for your own purpose. Have a look at the [intent library](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable) for specific intents that you might hijack for your application. You may find further information in the [android documentation on intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).