# Override default system volume button function globally

Tags: android, sdk, system

I need to override the default system volume key presses globally, for example: if I hit volume down from while in the main home launcher, it would execute the same command as it would when the application is running.

Comment: Seems duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934653/global-control-handler which has no answers either - anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: That is exactly what i would love an answer for in the ios after jail breaking your given an application named activator which basically is a global modification of all key events and touch gestures whichis nice but ijust need to modify the volume_key_down globally @Elemental

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write an intent for [Audio volume up](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/380), which will allow your app to intercept the broadcast message. You may then cancel the original action (of increasing the volume) and hijack the button for your own needs. Have a look in the [android developer documentation on intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) for example code and further information.

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) to get you started on BroadcastRecievers should get you started.

Comment: and this intent would be placed within the service on create?

Comment: Also I'd Appreciate if you can add some snipits examples these sites are vague on how to accomplish this exact function

Comment: I've added a tutorial on the topic as a link.

Comment: If I could vote you up on your answer I would how ever I am currently too new to this site to do so and despite that it requires me to do a lot of research and reading before I can get the code that I actually need but none the less this is the most progress I have achieved so far and nice tutorial btw :  )

Comment: @Lars, but how do we stop cancel the original action (of increasing the volume) as you suggest? Should we decrease it back? but in that case volume pop-up appears?