# Using hardware volume buttons to adjust brightness - without adjusting volume

Tags: android

I've come into somewhat of a weird predicament, the project I'm working on uses the volume rocker on the device to adjust the brightness of the device. This is done using a broadcast receiver that listens for android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION.

This all works fine, however, I can't seem to find a way to prevent the volume of the actual device changing in the process. I've looked at multiple avenues of different ways to approach this, but all come up the same path.

Could anyone point me into the right direction to get these buttons changing the brightness without the device volume changing? Or, is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check this, [Override default system volume button function globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212522/override-default-system-volume-button-function-globally)

Comment: @z.y thank you for your response, unfortunately this is quite old and does not work as intended anymore. I moved to using the Samsung Active button instead for my use case.